# Do not print outputs on terraform apply

Tags: terraform

Is there any way to prevent terraform from printing out the outputs when running `terraform apply`?

I've got several screens of outputs, and there are times where it would be handy to have the last thing printed to the screen be

> Apply complete! Resources: N added, N changed, N destroyed.

Comment: This is a really good clear question. Everything else I can find is about _sensitive_ information whereas some of us might want to access `output` only using `terraform output` without polluting `terraform apply`. If I am missing something feel free to link relevant information here

Answer (score 1):

The only built-in way to prevent Terraform from showing the output values after apply is to remove the declarations (the `output` blocks) from your root module.

If you want more control over how you display Terraform's progress, you can run `terraform apply -json` and pipe the output into a program you write yourself and interpret the JSON events into whatever UI presentation you wish.